# How to Implement Recycle Scroll View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

Currently I have using [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) for adding multiple view in recycle ScrollView, but in this library we can't use dynamic frames for every subview.

For Example: We have to create lot of `UITextView`, every textview have different frame sizes (Different Heights). So in this library it always creates 1024 frame and the remaining view in empty. It looks aweful.

I have tried many libraries but they are similar to SwipeView. So can any one suggest a library which will satisfy my constraints?

P.S: I have used `UITableView` but it takes too much time for `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: did u try this https://github.com/rydermackay/RGMPagingScrollView

Comment: @BalramTiwari Will Trying. Is this library support various frames for subview?

Answer (score 0):

`SwipeView` is just a container for arbitrary views representing the "pages". Your question is not completely clear, but it sounds like you use the `UITextViews` directly as pages? Why not wrap them in some other view, so that you can do any layouting that you might want?

Comment: Yes, I am using `UITextView` on `UIScollView` . I have more than 1000 `UITextView` . If I load it initially it will be give memory pressure, So only I am using Recyclable ScrollView like `SwipeView`

Comment: Sure. But you can return any view in `swipeView:viewForItemAtIndex:`. So why not return a custom view that includes the text view at the position/size that you want?